# How to access second array dimension index with Bayesplot?

Tags: rstan

I'm trying to plot the posterior areas with Bayesplot for a matrix of parameters. I haven't been able to use the second array dimension index in the `pars` argument to successfully plot my parameters. So I've defaulted to:

```
  bayesplot::color_scheme_set("viridis")
  bayesplot::mcmc_areas(as.data.frame(fitVodkaH), prob = 0.9, pars=c('alpha_age[1,1]'))
```

This works fine:

[image]

But if I try:

```
bayesplot::color_scheme_set("viridis")
  bayesplot::mcmc_areas(as.data.frame(fitVodkaH), prob = 0.9, pars=c('alpha_age'))
```

This fails:

```
Error in select_parameters(explicit = pars, patterns = regex_pars, complete = parnames) : Some 'pars' don't match parameter names: alpha_age
```

My model outputs look like what you'd expect:

```
alpha_age[1,1]          1.80    0.04 0.62     0.68     1.36     1.72     2.24     3.06   250 1.01
alpha_age[1,2]          0.43    0.02 0.37    -0.40     0.22     0.45     0.66     1.09   453 1.01
alpha_age[1,3]         -0.21    0.02 0.37    -1.01    -0.43    -0.22     0.04     0.49   542 1.00
alpha_age[1,4]         -0.64    0.02 0.43    -1.55    -0.90    -0.62    -0.35     0.18   728 1.00
alpha_age[2,1]          0.42    0.04 0.60    -0.63     0.00     0.28     0.83     1.62   231 1.01
alpha_age[2,2]         -0.18    0.02 0.34    -0.99    -0.35    -0.12     0.02     0.37   424 1.01
alpha_age[2,3]         -0.13    0.01 0.32    -0.83    -0.30    -0.08     0.04     0.46   490 1.00
alpha_age[2,4]         -0.01    0.01 0.35    -0.82    -0.17     0.00     0.16     0.69   701 1.00
alpha_age[3,1]         -0.86    0.04 0.65    -2.12    -1.33    -0.87    -0.33     0.20   268 1.01
alpha_age[3,2]         -0.02    0.01 0.34    -0.74    -0.21     0.00     0.18     0.60   548 1.01
alpha_age[3,3]          0.03    0.02 0.34    -0.68    -0.18     0.03     0.23     0.68   505 1.00
alpha_age[3,4]         -0.10    0.01 0.37    -0.91    -0.31    -0.07     0.11     0.63   656 1.01
alpha_age[4,1]         -2.14    0.04 0.75    -3.61    -2.63    -2.16    -1.62    -0.67   308 1.00
alpha_age[4,2]          0.84    0.02 0.36     0.07     0.63     0.86     1.06     1.45   403 1.01
alpha_age[4,3]          1.09    0.02 0.35     0.35     0.88     1.10     1.31     1.75   488 1.00
alpha_age[4,4]          1.70    0.01 0.38     0.93     1.50     1.71     1.90     2.44   667 1.00
```

Comment: Does `mcmc_areas` with `regex_pars = "^alpha_age"` work for you?

Comment: It does, thanks @BenGoodrich

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Ben Goodrich.

```
bayesplot::color_scheme_set("viridis")
  mcmc_areas(as.data.frame(fitVodkaH), prob = 0.9, regex_pars = "^theta")
```